# RegExp — Treat '\n' string as newline character

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a function that allows the user to specify a regex replacement.

They provide the target string and the replacement. However, currently if they provide \n, \t, etc as the replacement, it is treated as a string literal instead of the special character.

So, in short, given:

```
regex = new RegExp('\t','g');
replacement = '\n';

new_phrase = original_phrase.replace(regex, replacement);
```

Currently this will not insert actual newlines/tab characters.

How can I have \t and \n treated properly, as their special characters instead of string literals?

Comment: `'\\t'` and `'\\n'`. Escape the back-slash!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I do not think that is the case here. I think the input the user is using is acting like it is escaped, and not the new line.

Comment: "*Currently this will not replace/insert actual newlines/tab characters.*" - Yes, it will. Did you try it?

Comment: @epascarello That is exactly the case: the user types `\n` in the input, so it's is two characters (a \ and a n). So if he needs to replace it he must use `\\n` not `\n` as the first represent two chars and the latter represents one!

Comment: Updated to reflect that yes, it can target correctly, just not replace properly.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir... The textbox is used as a replacement. So the textbox value is already escaped.

Comment: @user179561 I think the only solution is to match the line feed and replace it in the user input. I am trying to think if there is a better way to do this...

Comment: @epascarello I think the user is intended to type the newline character instead of the two characters. So he must replace the input's value `\\n` into `\n` before using it to replace the string!

Comment: Where do you want to show the text? In a div? How do you set the new text?

Comment: OP wants a new line, not the string. The input is "\\n" (done with .value)  and wants it to actually be "\n"

Comment: Add something like `var dct = {'\\n': '\n', '\\r': '\r', '\\t': '\t' }; replacement = replacement.replace(/\\([tnr])/g, function($0) {return dct[$0];});`.

Comment: There is only one way to parse a string for escaped anything. The engine you use has to be able to do a negative lookbehind. In this case it can't be done any other way (easily). Example `(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*)(\\[\S\s])`. What does that mean ? If using JS, you're out of luck !!